Troubleshooting error in function 'numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used'
I have the below example data
example_data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:6,
  Month.Of.birth = c("September", "April", "December", "June", "April", "September"),
  year.of.birth = c(1942, 1942, 1938, 1946, 1944, 1946)
) 

I am trying to randomly assign a day of the year for each of the dates, to give a date of birth. I have built the below code, which initially worked then I put into my full code, and now generates an error Warning in 1:num_days_in_month :
numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
Does anyone know why?
generate_random_day_of_birth <- function(year, month) {
  if (is.na(year) || is.na(month)) {
    return(NA)
  }
  

  leap_year <- year %% 4 == 0 & (year %% 100 != 0 | year %% 400 == 0)
  
  num_days_in_month <- ifelse(month == "January", 31,
                              ifelse(month == "February" & !leap_year, 28,
                                     ifelse(month == "February" & leap_year, 29,
                                            ifelse(month %in% c("April", "June", "September", "November"), 30, 31))))
  
  random_day <- sample(1:num_days_in_month, 1)
  
  return(random_day)
}

example_data$day.of.birth <- generate_random_day_of_birth(example_data$year.of.birth, example_data$Month.Of.birth)


The warning is very clear. example_data$Month.Of.birth contains six values. Thus, num_days_in_month contains six values. : can only deal with one value on the right-hand side. It looks like you should loop over num_days_in_month. Something like sapply(num_days_in_month, sample, size = 1).

I think that the main problem is because your are not giving one pair of year-month, but 6 pairs, and your function has a hard time to manage it. Your function seems to behave well with generate_random_day_of_birth(example_data$year.of.birth[1], example_data$Month.Of.birth[1])
I am not sure what is the best way to handle this; but a simple tidyverse would be to use rowwise():
example_data %>% rowwise() %>%   mutate(dob= generate_random_day_of_birth(year.of.birth,Month.Of.birth)) %>%     ungroup()

As Roland mentioned in the comments, the following line:
sample(1:num_days_in_month, 1)

will return an error because the colon operator, when applied to numeric, generates a sequence of values from from to to and these must also be numeric values. They cannot be vectors. Your num_days_in_month object is a vector, thus the error.
A simple fix is to iterate over the vector using, say, sapply as mentioned in the comments.
sapply(num_days_in_month, sample, size = 1)

The other problem is on the first line:
if (is.na(year) || is.na(month)) {
    return(NA)
  }

Since year and month are vectors, you need to add the any function before each:
if (any(is.na(year)) || any(is.na(month))) {
    return(NA)
  }

You can also ignore January on the first line of your ifelse(...) statement.
  num_days_in_month <- ifelse(month == "February" & !leap_year, 28,
                              ifelse(month == "February" & leap_year, 29,
                                     ifelse(month %in% c("April", "June", "September", "November"), 30, 31)))


Tidyverse's lubridate::days_in_month(x) gives how many days a month have, but x must be a date-time object. You can set up a basic date with lubridate::ym() and pass it to days_in_month. Make a vector, and, rowwise, just sample one.
Try this:
library(tidyverse)
# ------------------

set.seed(100)

example_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    Month.Of.birth = fct(Month.Of.birth, levels = month.name),
    date = ym(str_glue("{year.of.birth}, {Month.Of.birth}")),
    date = ymd(str_glue("{year.of.birth}, {Month.Of.birth} {sample(1:days_in_month(date), 1)}")))

The output:
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     ID Month.Of.birth year.of.birth date      
  <int> <fct>                  <dbl> <date>    
1     1 September               1942 1942-09-10
2     2 April                   1942 1942-04-23
3     3 December                1938 1938-12-06
4     4 June                    1946 1946-06-16
5     5 April                   1944 1944-04-19
6     6 September               1946 1946-09-25

